# Python Matplotlib sumarising strings for a bar chart

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe that contains a persons age-range and whether they said yes or no to a question, what I'm aiming to do is have a bar chart that has the age-range values for the x axis but each one has the sum of the number of yes and nos that have occured

As an example my data looks like this:

```
Age Range    Received

21-30          Yes

21-30          Yes

31-40          No

31-40          No

21-30          No
```

So I'd want the graph to display the 21-30 and 31-40 as separate with 2 in yes and 1 in no for 21-30 and 2 in the no for 31-40.

I've used both groupby and mapping the yes and no values to 1 and 0 respectively but anything I've tried so far says that I either have no numerical values or display a widely unusable graph.

I can't share code unfortunately due to confidentiality issues but any help would be very appreciated

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Age Range'], df['Received']).plot.bar()`?

Comment: That's it thankyou!! You reduced my code from 20 lines to 1!!